# Searching function SQLite database with android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am attempting to create a search function that takes in a string, searches my local db, then outputs the contents found in a string. after that I display the string on btn click.

here is my search function.

```
public String Search(String n)
    {
        String info = "";
        Cursor cu = HRdb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM HRinfotbl WHERE (lname LIKE '"+n+"' OR fname LIKE '"+n+"';",null);
        int count = cu.getCount();
        cu.moveToFirst();
        for (Integer j = 0; j < count; j++)
        {
            info = info + 
                       "Surname : "+cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex("lname"))+"\n"+
                       "Name : "+cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex("fname"))+"\n"+
                       "Email : "+cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex("email"))+"\n"+
                       "Contact : "+cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex("contact"))+"\n\n";
            cu.moveToNext() ;
        }
        HRdb.close();
        return info;
    }
```

and here is other code that possibly influences it.

```
Button search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchbtn);
        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            dbView.setText(Search(searchtxt.getText().toString()));

        }
        });
```

hoping someone can lend a hand, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there's an SQL syntax error: missing `)` at the end. You can remove the parens.

Second, with `LIKE` you likely want to use `%` to match any number of any chars.

Third, use `?` placeholders and bind arguments instead of hardcoding any user input in SQL.

Example:

```
Cursor cu = HRdb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM HRinfotbl WHERE " +
    "lname LIKE '%' || ? || '%'  OR fname LIKE '%' || ? || '%'",
    new String[] { n, n });
```

where `||` is the string concatenation operator. I've also removed the `;` at end as it's not necessary.

Comment: I have attempted it, but still seem to not be working. All I changed is my query to yours, is there anything additionaly that I would need to change? I am very new to android. so sorry for dumb questions.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Exception? -> see exception stacktrace in logcat (you're logging the full exceptions, right?) No data? -> First make sure there is data to begin with. Other? -> Use a debugger.

Comment: ahh got it, was syntax error ;) Thank you for your help, your search function works 100%

Answer (score 0):

i think it's not safe, i suggest for searching like this

```
Cursor cu = HRdb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM HRinfotbl WHERE (lname LIKE ? OR fname LIKE ?;", new String[]{n, n});
```